# Is a comparison operation thread safe for std::atomic variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

`std::atomic` has some operators like: +, -, ++, -- (post and pre) and guarantee that they are thread safe, but is comparison operations thread safe? I mean following:

```
std::atomic<int> a = 10;
int i = 20;

void func() {
  a++; // atomic and thread safe
  if (a > i) // is it thread safe? 
}
```

Comment: `i` is not atomic. how can it be thread-safe?

Comment: @Nawaz: If all threads only read from `i`, then that's okay.

Comment: My mistake. `i` is a constant variable. It only for reading.

Comment: @Cornstalks: I said that because `i` is not a const expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is thread-safe only if:

- `i` never changes (you really should make it `const`)
- You don't expect that if `a++` changes the value to be larger than `i`, that a successive atomic load will satisfy `a > i`.  Two separate atomic instructions are not atomic.
- You don't require the branching code to be atomic

Note the last point here.  You are free to compare `a > i`.  This will atomically acquire the current value of `a` and then use that value to compare against `i`.  However the actual value of `a` might change immediately afterwards.  As long as your branch doesn't rely on that not happening, this is fine.

```
if( a > i )
{
    // a is not guaranteed to be greater than i at this point.
}
```

I'm not quite sure how you want your logic to work, but it's possible you might have meant this:

```
if( ++a > i )
{
    // a is still not guaranteed to be greater than i at this point,
    // but AT THE TIME OF INCREMENTING it did exceed i.
}
```